# "PageSpeed Insights" not show extrenal Files?

Tags: webpack, pagespeed

Our website has a problem with `PSI`. 
`PSI` didn't find the external Files (images, CSS usw.).

Nows everyone why is that so?

`PSI-Error`

[image]

Comment: Maybe the external files need to be whitelisted in some security constraint.

Comment: Check your `robots.txt` to see if the external files are listed there.

Comment: I dont have a robots.txt. I have no idea from who can comes this problem. Has anyone an soultion why this coming. Here is the code form Webpack:

Comment: import '../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css';
import '../node_modules/milligram/dist/milligram.css';
import '../node_modules/luxbar/scss/luxbar.scss';
import '../node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css';
import '../node_modules/lightgallery.js/src/css/lightgallery.css';
import '../node_modules/lightgallery.js/src/js/lightgallery.js';
import SmoothScroll from '../node_modules/smooth-scroll/dist/js/smooth-scroll.min.js';
import gumshoe from '../node_modules/gumshoe/dist/js/gumshoe.js';
import './fontello.css';
import './index.scss';

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox what do you mean with **security constraint**?

Comment: Maybe you use some security framework that will block any resources by default